# Checking if SSD died

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I've got a serious problem with my SSD.

Once, it failed to boot and all of partitions were lost. I managed to recover partitions by sticking it as an external drive to other PC. I copied all the data and formatted drive and reinstalled Windows. Then, the same thing happend 3 or 4 times. I suspect that SSD is damaged, but every health check tool I use doesn't detect any bad sectors or poor health. I tried installing Windows 10, then Windows 8.1, but on both OS partitions were lost after few hours of using.

Does anybody know if there is any other way to check what the real condtiion of SSD is? Maybe there is another way to check if it's SSD fault or maybe my laptop is faulty?

Comment: change the cable.

Comment: I am working on a notebook, so I am using direct SATA

Comment: Diagnostic tools only show an approximation of the SSD health. If it fails, it fails, and needs replacement.

Comment: SSD brand? Can you post a CrystalDiskInfo screenshot? Did you check the SSD in another machine for a while? Check if laptop's fault: try with a different SSD.